# Tradução para o português de 'we have reproved'

Tags: português-brasileiro, gramática, tradução-inglês

Consideremos o [texto abaixo](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/differential-and-integral-equations/volume-28/issue-5_2f_6/On-the-spectral-stability-of-periodic-waves-of-the-Klein/die/1427744096.short) ([e-print](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/287814368_ON_THE_SPECTRAL_STABILITY_OF_PERIODIC_WAVES_OF_THE_KLEIN-GORDON_EQUATION)):

[image]

Na sentença *Thus, we have reproved the result in [10]*, qual é o significado de ***we have reproved*** dentro do contexto do texto? Significa 'reprovar' no sentido de 'rejeitar', 'recusar', 'refutar'? Ou sentido de 'confirmar'? Pois na língua portuguesa quando queremos confirmar algo já feito usamos o prefixo "re", como por exemplo, 'refazer', 'reler'. Então, minha dúvida é se o *we have reproved* pode significar que o resultado em [10] foi "provado novamente", foi "confirmado novamente". Ou só por esse pequeno trecho do texto não é possível dizer? Pois, pode ser que apenas esse trecho não dê o contexto necessário para tirar conclusões.

<sub>Ref.: *On the spectral stability of periodic waves of the Klein-Gordon equation*, Demirkaya et al, Differential Integral Equations 28(5/6): 431-454 (May/June 2015).</sub>

Comment: Oi Guilherme, adicionei links e a referência do artigo que contém o trecho que te suscitou a dúvida - se você preferir incluir a informação de outra forma, não hesite em reeditar a questão. :)

Comment: reproved aqui quer dizer provar de novo.

Answer (score 5):

"*Reprove*" significa "reprovar", "criticar", mas o contexto indica que a intenção era denotar "provar novamente"; isso fica especialmente claro no resumo do artigo:

> Our results generalize recent work on the simpler case of standing waves of Natali-Pastor, [9] and Natali-Cardoso, [10].

Uma possibilidade é que esteja faltando um hífen e palavra deveria ter sido [*re-prove*](https://www.wordreference.com/definition/re-prove), incomum nos dicionários, mas usada na literatura de matemática (e.g., [aqui](https://doi.org/10.1093/philmat/nkl009)).

Comment: Eu fiquei com a mesma sensação, pelo que está no resumo também, como você comentou.

Answer (score 0):

O hífen realmente não é muito utilizado aqui.

Em termos matemáticos, *reprove* significa "provar de novo", no sentido the verificar os resultados para confirmar se a proposicao original foi realmente provada (testada) corretamente, ou se o resultado é diferente do esperado.

Leia nesse post que cobra a importância de re-avaliar (re-testar, provar de novo o que já foi provado) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4128594/what-is-the-mathematical-value-of-reproving-theorems